# How to convert a integer to ordinal string in python jinja templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to replace 1 with 1st, 2 with 2nd, and so on, in the jinja template.

Currently, I'm using the following code, but it is throwing SyntaxError

```py
{{ "%d%s"% (no_of_owners, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}
```

where no_of_owners is a string like "5".
What should be the correct way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear:

```
TypeError: %d format: a real number is required, not str
```

You're trying to format a string using `%d`, which doesn't make any sense. You could simply replace it with `%s`:

```
>>> t = jinja2.Template('''{{ "%s%s"% (no_of_owners, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}''')
>>> print(t.render(no_of_owners="5"))
5th
```

Or add the `int` filter:

```
>>> t = jinja2.Template('''{{ "%d%s"% (no_of_owners|int, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}''')
>>> print(t.render(no_of_owners="5"))
5th
```

### Update 1

Here's a runnable version of the above examples:

```
import jinja2

print("=== using %s instead of %d ===")
t = jinja2.Template('''{{ "%s%s"% (no_of_owners, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}''')
print(t.render(no_of_owners="5"))
print()

print("=== using int filter ===")
t = jinja2.Template('''{{ "%d%s"% (no_of_owners|int, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}''')
print(t.render(no_of_owners="5"))
print()
```

I'm testing this using Jinja2 3.0.3 and Python 3.11.

### Update 2

The above code also works with Python 3.6 and Jinja2 2.10.1:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.15 (default, Dec 21 2021, 12:03:22)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.__version__
'2.10.1'
>>> t = jinja2.Template('''{{ "%s%s"% (no_of_owners, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}''')
>>> print(t.render(no_of_owners="5"))
5th
>>> t = jinja2.Template('''{{ "%d%s"% (no_of_owners|int, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners|int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4]) }}''')
>>> print(t.render(no_of_owners="5"))
5th
```

Comment: Getting the same error after using this as well.


```TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: "%s%s"|% (no_of_owners, "tsnrhtdd"[(no_of_owners||int//10%10!=1) * (no_of_owners|int%10<4) * no_of_owners|int%10 :: 4])```

Comment: The code I've included in this answers runs without errors; this is verbatim interaction with the Python console. I'm using Python 3.11 and Jinja version 3.0.3.

Comment: If you copy and paste the runnable example I've just added to the answer, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: I'm using `Jinja2==2.10.1` version

Comment: It looks like you're also using an older version of Python, which is definitely worth noting in your question.